# How to delete maximo anywhere offline local data from iPad

Tags: ios, local-storage, maximo, maximo-anywhere

Currently have Work execution app installed on an iPad but from time to time completed work orders get stuck on the work list although they have been updated in Maximo so should clear off the work list.

I have been told it may be a cache issue and to delete local storage or cache for the application.

Can this be done via an application? Or will I need to customise the app?

Comment: This is just bad design on the part of Maximo Anywhere. The issue is that your offline set of work orders are downloaded, but the orphaned work orders are not handled. Thus you have a sync issue where the status of work orders (although complete) remain in limbo on the client device. If the work order is orphaned, it should be removed from the local cache rather than being able to live on abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

According to our design workorders should always be removed from your worklist once they no longer match the worklist query. I think you are hitting a bug where sometimes the Work Orders do not get removed from the work list when they should.  Please open a PMR with our support to track.